# How can I delete in SSIS a FlatFile in ControlFlow when it has dynamic name?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, flat-file

I use `SQL Server 2016` and I have a SSIS package in which I have created a `FlatFile` with a `dynamic Name` in one DataFlow in Loop.

For creating the name I have used this pathern : 
"SomeText" + `DateTime` + "SomeText"

[image]

I have created a varibale like below Image :

[image]

This is Exprission in my variable:

[image]

Then I have assigned this variable to connectionString properties of my FlatFile Destination like this :

[image]

In some case in `DataFlow` I don't have the data and I create an empty file but I need to delete this file when it is empty. Because of that I have created a Variable and I have used `RowCount Component` for populate this variable.

[image]

After that in `Control Flow`, I have put a `File System Task` for deleting the file if my variable is 0. (My loop is based on a object)

[image]

But I have an issue, In `DataFlow`, When I want to delete the file, the name of `FlatFile` will be changed and I can't find the same file that has been created in `DataFlow`.

The problem is that value of variable will be change in second time when I want use the variable.

How can I delete a `Flat File` in `Control Flow` which has been created dynamically in `DataFlow`?

Comment: Store the dynamic name in a variable, then you will have it anywhere

Comment: @FLICKER Dynamic name is now in the variable but I have this issue. Each time that we want read the value of variable it will be initialize and it takes the new value because of datetime part

Comment: Please show us where/how you are setting the filename variable in relation to the dataflow task.  You shouldnt have to reinitialize the variable if it has proper scope (package level).

Comment: Can you explain the source of your data that you are populating in Flatfile? and How empty files are created?

Comment: @JiggsJedi: I have updated my post

Comment: @Viki888: The source of data really is not matter. I have several source in my Dataflow more than ten source of data and in some condition in some where in my Dataflow i should create a FlatFile with CSV format. But this file should not be created if it is empty. but in DataFlow when FlatFile destination initialize, it will be created.  I need to delete this file when it is empty. I have a loop in Control flow in some object variable and for each row in my object i should run my dataflow. That means i can run DataFlow 0  or more and that means I can have zero or more FlatFile with dynamic name

Comment: You should really fix the code that creates empty files in the first place rather than adding a whole lot of complex cleanup code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : How can i avoid to create a empty file in DataFlow?

Comment: I don't know - you didn't really explain how you're doing it - you just said: _In some case in DataFlow I don't have the data and I create an empty file_. You could for example count the number of records in the source before you try and extract them and if there are zero, skip the extraction step.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : that was my bad. Imagine in my Dataflow is a condition split in some condition (number > 10 for example) I have one brunch of DataFlow and in case of Number>= 10 i have other brunch of DataFlow. In first flow, I have some Lookup and after that in one condition split I will decide what should i do (Insert into Error table or Insert Into flat file). The flat file is my goal but i don't want to have empty flat file. but even if my dataflow goes to insert to error table, it will create a empty file.

Comment: I disagree with stating you should count first... its situational.  If the table has 500 rows, sure, why not...  But if it has 500 million, maybe not.  It could take significantly longer to execute the job if it has to connect/query twice.

Comment: Yes it's situational. We have no idea of the situation here. But you're right that would be horribly inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a script task to set your variable value, not an expression builder.

Since you are using a date/time in the expression builder, it is constantly changing.  Using a script task will allow you to capture/store the date/time value as the loop iterates, and store that value persistently throughout the loop.

This script task would typically be at the top (first) of your loop, and it would set/change the filename on every iteration.

Here are some examples of how to do this:
https://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ca/2010/12/how-to-use-variables-in-script-task.html

If you are getting values within the dataflow which are used in the filename, then you may need to use a script component (transformation) to update the filename within the dataflow.

Here are some examples of how to do this: https://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ca/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Put that delete step in a for each loop. Foreach File Enumerator with a wild card file name mask. [image: For each]

with an output string variable which will be the file name its found and you can put that in your delete variable

Comment: I don't have a foreach in folder. My for each in on an object. Inside of my dataflow I create the flat file with dynamic name. and then if the file is empty i want delete my file but i dont know what was the name of file.